# How to save multiple files with incrementing names using pywinauto

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, pywinauto

I'm trying to write a simple script that will increment the text inside of a file by +1 and then save the file while incrementing the file name by +1.

So basically:

This is text 1

Saved as: File1.txt

This is text 2

Saved as: File2.txt

And so on. I've gotten my script to do this with the notepad program however I can't figure out a way to do this without having to open notepad for every file.
I've played around with trying to connect to the process id and such but I'm only about a month into programming so I'm having a terrible time with the concept.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pywinauto.application import Application
b = int(raw_input("Where do you want to start? >"))
a = int(raw_input("How Many Labels do you need? >"))

def make_labels(a, b):

    app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
    app.UntitledNotepad.edit1.SetText("This is me typing %r" % b)
    app.UntitledNotepad.MenuSelect("File -> SaveAs")
    #app.SaveAs.ComboBox5.Select("UTF-8")
    app.SaveAs.edit1.SetText("Test_File%r.txt" % b)
    app.SaveAs.Save.Click()
    app.UntitledNotepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
    b = b + 1
    return b



while b < a:
    b = make_labels(a, b)
```

Any help at all figuring out how to get this to work only using one instance of notepad would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Okay so I've made a little progress I think. I didn't know that you could just identify it by the program name so I changed that and now it uses the same window. However my new issue is that it will get to the point where it increments the contents by +1 a second time however it will fail to open the save option afterwards:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

b = int(raw_input("Where do you want to start? >"))
a = int(raw_input("How Many Labels do you need? >"))
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")

def make_labels(b, app): 

    #app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
    app.Notepad.edit1.SetText("This is me typing %r" % b)
    app.Notepad.MenuSelect("File -> SaveAs")
    app.SaveAs.edit1.SetText("Test_File%r.txt" % b)
    app.SaveAs.Save.Click()

    #app.Notepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
    b = b + 1
    return b



while b < a:
     b = make_labels(b, app)
```

Comment: If you're asking "how do I read data from a file, then create a file with a new name, and write information in it?", [Reading and Writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), [Reading and Writing Files in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python), [Python Files I/O](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Comment: No I've got that down (mostly) i just need to change the text slightly (by incrementing the number at the end of the sentence by +1) and then do the same to the title of the save file. I've got those parts down and the script works to that effect however currently it's opening a new instance of notepad every time it makes a change. I want it to use the same instance of notepad but cant figure out how to get it to connect to that instance because the instance name changes to the name of the saved file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright!

So I figured out an alternate way of solving my problem. Instead of using the menu select option as if a person was clicking it with their mouse I instead tried an all Keyboard Shortcut way and it worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

b = int(raw_input("Where do you want to start? >"))
a = int(raw_input("How Many Labels do you need? >"))
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")

def make_labels(b, app): 

    #app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
    app.Notepad.edit1.SetText("This is me typing %r" % b)
    app.Notepad.TypeKeys("^S")
    app.SaveAs.edit1.SetText("Test_File%r.txt" % b)
    app.SaveAs.Save.Click()

    #app.Notepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
    b = b + 1
    return b



while b < a:
    b = make_labels(b, app)
    app.Notepad.TypeKeys("^N")
```

This uses the keyboard inputs to save the file and then open a new file (under the same application instance) and repeat the process.

I hope this can be helpful to someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Writing twice the line

```
app.SaveAs.Save.Click()
```

Seems to solve the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pywinauto.application import Application
b = int(raw_input("Where do you want to start? >"))
a = int(raw_input("How Many Labels do you need? >"))

def make_labels(a, b):

    app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
    app.UntitledNotepad.edit1.SetText("This is me typing %r" % b)
    app.UntitledNotepad.MenuSelect("File -> SaveAs")
    #app.SaveAs.ComboBox5.Select("UTF-8")
    app.SaveAs.edit1.SetText("Test_File%r.txt" % b)
    app.SaveAs.Save.Click()
    app.SaveAs.Save.Click()
    app.UntitledNotepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
    b = b + 1
    return b

while b < a:
    b = make_labels(a, b)
```

Then in your function make_labels the arguments 'a' is useless.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that a is useless in the function too. That was a neglected leftover from me trying to figure the first bits out but thank you for pointing it out. I got past the identifying the window for the script to work on part however I seem to have a new issue that I've detailed in an update to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you actually want the Notepad window to appear, or if you're only interested in writing the file using whatever works, and that's the first approach you found that worked. If it's the latter, you don't need `pywinauto` to save multiple files. `open` and `write` will work just fine.

```
b = int(raw_input("Where do you want to start? > "))
a = int(raw_input("How Many Labels do you need? >"))
for x in range(b, b+a):
    with open("Test_file{}.txt".format(x), "w") as file:
        file.write("This is me typing {}".format(x))
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have mentioned that this is a pilot to getting a different (somewhat obscure industrial) program to go through these motions. I have the menu selecting and navigation down mostly but the logic of the process is what's getting me.